# I'm trying to display the amount of sales from a specific time frame

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm making a sales report through a specific from date1 to date2.. where total of amount will be displayed as well count the number of records. unfortunately i got this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$run_report' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\admin_area\view_sales.php on line 154

TABLE:  payments.tbl

```
 payment_id amount  customer_id product_id  trx_id  currency    payment_date
 21     10470        1       15      5F110606611093636  PHP    2015-03-30
```

NOTE: payment_date structure is DATE

WHAT I GOT SO FAR:

Generate Report

```
From:</td>
<td  align=left  > 
<select name="month" value="Select Month"></option>
<option value='01'>January</option>
<option value='02'>February</option>
<option value='03'>March</option>
<option value='04'>April</option>
<option value='05'>May</option>
<option value='06'>June</option>
<option value='07'>July</option>
<option value='08'>August</option>
<option value='09'>September</option>
<option value='10'>October</option>
<option value='11'>November</option>
<option value='12'>December</option>
</select>
</td>
<td  align=left  >   
Date:
<select name="day" >
<option value='01'>01</option>
<option value='02'>02</option>
<option value='03'>03</option>
<option value='04'>04</option>
<option value='05'>05</option>
<option value='06'>06</option>
<option value='07'>07</option>
<option value='08'>08</option>
<option value='09'>09</option>
<option value='10'>10</option>
<option value='11'>11</option>
<option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
<option value='15'>15</option>
    <option value='16'>16</option>
<option value='17'>17</option>
<option value='18'>18</option>
<option value='19'>19</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
<option value='21'>21</option>
<option value='22'>22</option>
<option value='23'>23</option>
<option value='24'>24</option>
<option value='25'>25</option>
<option value='26'>26</option>
<option value='27'>27</option>
<option value='28'>28</option>
<option value='29'>29</option>
<option value='30'>30</option>
<option value='31'>31</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
Year(yyyy)<input type=text name="year" size=4 value=2015>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td  align=left  > 


To :
</td>
<td  align=left  > 
<select name="month2" value=''>Select Month</option>
<option value='01'>January</option>
<option value='02'>February</option>
<option value='03'>March</option>
<option value='04'>April</option>
<option value='05'>May</option>
<option value='06'>June</option>
<option value='07'>July</option>
<option value='08'>August</option>
<   option value='09'>September</option>
<option value='10'>October</option>
<option value='11'>November</option>
<option value='12'>December</option>
</select>

</td><td  align=left  >   
Date :<select name="day2" >
<option value='01'>01</option>
<option value='02'>02</option>
<option value='03'>03</option>
<option value='04'>04</option>
<option value='05'>05</option>
<option value='06'>06</option>
<option value='07'>07</option>
<option value='08'>08</option>
<option value='09'>09</option>
<option value='10'>10</option>
<option value='11'>11</option>
<option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
<option value='15'>15</option>
<option value='16'>16</option>
<option value='17'>17</option>
<option value='18'>18</option>
<option value='19'>19</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
<option value='21'>21</option>
<option value='22'>22</option>
<option value='23'>23</option>
<option value='24'>24</option>
<option value='25'>25</option>
<option value='26'>26</option>
<option value='27'>27</option>
<option value='28'>28</option>
<option value='29'>29</option>
<option value='30'>30</option>
<option value='31'>31</option>
</select>


</td><td  align=left  >   
Year(yyyy)<input type=text name="year2" size=4 value=2015>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" name="gen_report" value="GENERATE REPORT">
</td>
</tr>
</table>


</form>

<?Php

include("includes/db.php");
if(isset($_POST['gen_report'])){
$month=$_POST['month'];
$day=$_POST['day'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$month2=$_POST['month2'];
$day2=$_POST['day2'];
$year2=$_POST['year2'];
$date_value="$year-$month-$day";
$date_value2="$year2-$month2-$day2";

$get_report = "select * from payments 
    where payment_date >= '$date_value' AND payment_date < '$date_value2'"

$run_report = mysqli_query($con, $get_report); 
while ($row_report=mysqli_fetch_array($run_report)){
$report_date = $row_report['payment_date'];
$report_cust = $row_report['customer_id'];
$amount = array($row_report['amount']);
$total_amount = array_sum($amount);
$total =+ $total_amount;
SALES REPORT FROM: $date_value to $date_value2;
$total;

}
}
?>
```

Comment: missing `;` to terminate the line, typo

Comment: Having used => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have signaled the parse error.

Comment: why it says Notice: Undefined variable: total in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\admin_area\view_sales.php on line 164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $get_report = "select * from payments 
where payment_date >= '$date_value' AND payment_date < '$date_value2'";  <---
```

missing a semicolon (`;`)

Comment: the code is working but i got this error Notice: Undefined variable: total in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\admin_area\view_sales.php on line 164